# Haskell. Why it is working? (Iteration over Monad)

Tags: haskell, io-monad

```
liftMM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
liftMM f m = m >>= \a -> return (f a)
```

I run:

```
> liftMM (*2) [1..10]
```

I got output:

```
> [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

I can not see how this function is mapping over all list's values? There is no any recursion or iteration, just one pass monad internal m value to the function f. What I am missing here?

Comment: The definition of `>>=` for `[]` is just `concatMap` - this function is precisely what does the mapping.

Comment: You have used the monad laws to define `fmap`.

Comment: Wasn't the first time I found `>>=` confusing in this context. Has nothing to do with Monads here.

Comment: @ vikingsteve I guess list [] is a monad. That's why >>= defined for the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` here is `[]` and `liftMM` works by delegating to the implementation of `(>>=)` and `return` for `m`. Therefore you need to understand `(>>=)` and `return` for lists, and if you look at the [definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-726) they are:

```
instance Monad []  where
    xs >>= f            = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]
    return x            = [x]
```

so for each element in the source list `>>=` applies `f` and then inserts each element of the returned list into the result list.

`return x` simply returns a singleton list containing `x` so `return (f a)` returns a list `[f a]`. Each of these single element lists are then combined by `(>>=)` to create the output list.

Answer (score 0):

A list is a `monad`, so given the signature for map:

`map :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]`

and the signature for liftMM

`liftMM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`

the `[]` is the `m`

This means that **for lists** `liftMM` and `map` do the same thing.